# Usefulness of space where metric defined but not norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

This question is similar to the one below:

[Examples of metric vector spaces but not normed ? Normed but not prehilbertian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736410/examples-of-metric-vector-spaces-but-not-normed-normed-but-not-prehilbertian)

But I would like to know if there any application of the space where metric is defined but not the norm. As in the above it was pointed out that metric is invariant under translation. Is there any other limitation of space where we cannot define norm?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146654/normable-lf-space/1146678#1146678 . Look at Daniel Fischer's response.

Comment: @T.A.E. Thank you. Is such a space is useful? Can we apply it somewhere?

Comment: I think that the examples Daniel gives are significant spaces whose strong duals are as you want.